# Unable to run the server by binding the public IP shown in the azure portal

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

I have developed a node.js application and trying to deploy my app in windows server 2012R2 from Azure.

When i'm trying to start the server by specifying the IP as "104.11.43.216" which is shown as the Public IP of the virtual machine in the portal, thinking that the applicaton can be accessed outside my virtual machine. But it fails to start with an error saying 'listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 104.11.43.216'.

If i specify the IP which i get as IPV4 from the system, I mean using the Virtual IP "10.0.0.4" the app runs perfectly but can be accessed only inside the VM.

How can i make the application to accessed outside my virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think you need to add a new endpoint for the listening port of your application for the public ip of the VM, then you can try to access the address `IP:port` from internet outside VM.

If you are using Azure old portal, please add the new endpoint at the tab `ENDPOINTS`, please see the figure below.
[image]

If you are using Azure new portal, please see the figure below.
[image]

Comment: Pan, I do not get EndPoints option in all settings of my virtual machine. Am using new portal.

Comment: @Shyamkumar Could you share more information for helping analyze the issue? Such as the figure shown all settings of your VM, the steps of your creation for VM, etc.

Comment: No. there was no options as it is in your screenshot. Thanks